# Animate multiple data files in GNU-Plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have around 1000 data files (filenames: data1.dat, data2.dat...... data1000.dat). 
I am trying to animate them and create a single gif image.
However i have failed to do so from the past 12 hours.
The gif file gets created but it only displays the first image.

Please have a look at my code and suggest me necessary edits.
Thanks

```
set terminal gif
set output "output.gif"
set xr[0:400]
set yr[-50000:50000]
set xlabel 'Space between electrodes(um)'
set ylabel 'Electric field (V/m)'
set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "red" lw 1
do for [i=1:100] {
   plot sprintf('data%d.dat', i) with linespoints ls 1 pointtype 0 title sprintf('data%d.dat', i)
   pause 0.1
   reread
 }
set output
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use animate, like:

`set terminal gif animate delay 10`

where 10 means 10/100 s delay between frames. See `help terminal gif` in `gnuplot` for more details.

You can also consider using another terminal (e.g. pngcairo) generating separate images by moving `set output sprintf('frame%03.0f.png',i)` inside the `do` loop. Then you can join the frames using e.g. `mencoder`, `ffmpeg` or even `convert` `(convert -loop 0 frame*.png output.gif)`. In this way you can end up with something else than .gif. And you don't need `pause` in the loop neither.